liquibase commands to check the chageset difference in b/w existing and the pr-checkout changeset
In github workflow while deploying the database changes with liquibase, we need identify the difference between the existing changelog and the pr-checkout changeslog.
To identify these changeset differences, I have used the liquibase command:"unexpected-changesets". The unexpected-changesets command is typically used to detect and compare the changes between the DATABASECHANGELOG table and the current changelog.
I just want to know, Is this is right approach or any other approach/commands we can use to detect the difference in b/w existing chageset and the pr-checkout changeset.

You can also use status command: lists all undeployed changesets - it also lists the id, author, and file path name for each undeployed changeset . It provides the following output:
Liquibase Open Source [local build] by Liquibase
1 changeset has not been applied to LBUSER@jdbc:h2:mem:liquibase
     changelogs/changelog/createTableChangelog.xml::1::fl
Liquibase command 'status' was executed successfully.

